# Piano lever on lefthand side of upright piano

Tags: piano

[image]

Does anyone know what this lever, in  the picture, which is located after the bass keys on an upright piano, is for?

Comment: Please add the piano manufacturer, which might help find the answer.

Comment: Some other helpful items: 1) have you tried it? 2) If yes, what happened? 3) How many pedals does the piano have? 4) If you lift the top lid, is there a piece of felt that runs the length of the keyboard?

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't seem to make a difference when played. The piano has 3 pedals.

Comment: It's a Heintzman, and no there is no felt.

Comment: Being Canadian, the middle pedal is probably a sostenuto pedal. Leaving the option of a quiet practice device operated by the lever. It may well not still be connected/work, but at one time would possibly have the same effect as slightly damping the strings - maybe by use of a felt curtain that went between the hammers and the strings. Best look inside and tell us what you can see moving. Clue to middle pedal - locking or not? Need more info!

Answer (score 1):

You need to look inside the piano, to see what mechanism the 'knob' is attached to, if any, still. It may be that the practice curtain that it maybe was used to operate has been removed. As a three pedal piano, from Canada, the chances are the pedals are soft, sostenuto, sustain, from left to right.

Heintzman pianos were the best made in Canada, and well thought of. It could be that this was made with the regular three pedals, but also a practice device, which no longer exists, for whatever reason. Checking inside may reveal something you missed. Or even something missing!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a damper knob

[image: Damper Knob]

Image from https://blog.rivertonpiano.com/2019/12/19/what-do-a-pianos-pedals-do/

Comment: Some more explanation would be helpful in case the link ever goes dead.

Comment: I think that picture is of an antique instrument, substituting for a sustain pedal.

Comment: The illustration purports to be of a very early piano, the knob substitutes for a sustain pedal.  Though I'm suspicious.  The casework looks very modern...